# Can't compile a simple hello world using GHC 7.8rc2 and Windows 7 (or install packages with cabal)

Tags: windows, haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

I can't compile a simple hello world or install packages with cabal install when using `ghc 7.8`, `cabal 1.18.1.3` and `cabal-install 1.18.0.2`.

When doing a `cabal install stm` (or any other package) from a command prompt Windows shows a "ghc.exe has stopped working" window, and the output is:

```
Reading available packages...
Choosing modular solver.
Resolving dependencies...
Ready to install stm-2.4.2
Extracting
Waiting for install task to finish...
C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\cabal\packages\hackage.haskell.org\stm\2.4.2\stm-2.4.2.tar.gz
to C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\stm-2.4.2-6556...
Updating stm.cabal with the latest revision from the index.
Configuring stm-2.4.2...
creating C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\stm-2.4.2-6556\stm-2.4.2\dist\setup
creating C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\stm-2.4.2-6556\stm-2.4.2\dist
creating C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\stm-2.4.2-6556\stm-2.4.2\dist\setup
"c:\ghc-7.8.0\bin\ghc.exe" "--make" "-odir" "C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\stm-2.4.2-6556\stm-2.4.2\dist\setup" "-hidir" "C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\stm-2.4.2-6556\stm-2.4.2\dist\setup" "-i" "-iC:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\stm-2.4.2-6556\stm-2.4.2" "-package-id" "Cabal-1.18.1.3-ac8664a5c71d605f2a4a8e21170969e0" "C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\stm-2.4.2-6556\stm-2.4.2\dist\setup\setup.hs" "-o" "C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp\stm-2.4.2-6556\stm-2.4.2\dist\setup\setup.exe"
Failed to install stm-2.4.2
Last 10 lines of the build log ( C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\stm-2.4.2.log ):
World file is already up to date.
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
stm-2.4.2 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
user error
```

I installed(?) `GHC 7.8` and `cabal-install` with the following steps

- Downloaded GHC 7.8 RC2 (http://www.haskell.org/ghc/dist/7.8.1-rc2/ghc-7.8.0.20140228-i386-unknown-mingw32.tar.bz2)
- Extracted the contents of the tar to folder $GHC$
- Added  $GHC$\bin and $GHC$\mingw\bing folder to the PATH.
- Downloaded prebuilt cabal-install (
  http://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-install-1.18.0.2/cabal.exe)
- Copied cabal.exe to $GHC$\bin so it's in the path
- Run `cabal update`
- Run `cabal install stm`  (or any other package)

Before doing all this, I uninstalled my previous Haskell Platform, deleted folders cabal and ghc from `%USER%\AppData\Roaming`, and other haskell stuff from the `Program Files` folder.

I am not sure if GHC needed any additional installation steps

I need GHC 7.8 because I want to try out GHCJS.

**PS**:

I also added `LANG=C` to my env variables so that compiling does not throw a UTF-8 encoding error.

`cabal --version` **shows**:

```
cabal-install version 1.18.0.2
using version 1.18.1 of the Cabal library
```

Which seems to be ok except that the cabal library shows up as 1.18.1 instead of 1.18.1.3, but i'm not sure that's an error.

`ghc-pkg list` shows:

```
c:/ghc-7.8.0\lib\package.conf.d:
Cabal-1.18.1.3
Win32-2.3.0.1
array-0.5.0.0
base-4.7.0.0
bin-package-db-0.0.0.0
binary-0.7.1.0
rts-1.0
bytestring-0.10.4.0
containers-0.5.4.0
deepseq-1.3.0.2
directory-1.2.0.2
filepath-1.3.0.2
(ghc-7.8.0.20140228)
ghc-prim-0.3.1.0
(haskell2010-1.1.1.1)
(haskell98-2.0.0.3)
hoopl-3.10.0.0
hpc-0.6.0.1
integer-gmp-0.5.1.0
old-locale-1.0.0.6
old-time-1.1.0.2
pretty-1.1.1.1
process-1.2.0.0
template-haskell-2.9.0.0
time-1.4.1
transformers-0.3.0.0
```

** EDIT **: Trying to compile stm manually by going into its folder and running `ghc` generates the same error window and gives the output:

**EDIT 2**: Actually, I can't even compile a simple hello world with `ghc helloworld.hs`:

main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"

Compiling with "-v3" gives the following (uninformative) output:

```
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.8.0.20140228, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.6.3
Using binary package database: C:\ghc-7.8.0\lib\package.conf.d\package.cache
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.3.1.0-ce20d91f79b43ede95508e8cfd2188b0
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-0.5.1.0-67cd00feecdc491a633c46b0f7652b46
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.7.0.0-d4a0afe8e5c5f0dff2237b1231b56978
wired-in package rts mapped to builtin_rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.9.0.0-f798cb95c80f3e3751ec33b413381b57
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
Hsc static flags:
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.3.1.0-ce20d91f79b43ede95508e8cfd2188b0
wired-in package integer-gmp mapped to integer-gmp-0.5.1.0-67cd00feecdc491a633c46b0f7652b46
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.7.0.0-d4a0afe8e5c5f0dff2237b1231b56978
wired-in package rts mapped to builtin_rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.9.0.0-f798cb95c80f3e3751ec33b413381b57
wired-in package dph-seq not found.
wired-in package dph-par not found.
*** Chasing dependencies:
Chasing modules from: *asd.hs
Stable obj: []
Stable BCO: []
Ready for upsweep
  [NONREC
      ModSummary {
         ms_hs_date = 2014-03-10 04:11:51 UTC
         ms_mod = main:Main,
         ms_textual_imps = [import (implicit) Prelude]
         ms_srcimps = []
      }]
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting:
compile: input file asd.hs
Created temporary directory: C:\Users\facuq\AppData\Local\Temp\ghc6824_1
*** Checking old interface for main:Main:
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( asd.hs, asd.o )
*** Parser:
*** Renamer/typechecker:
*** Desugar:
Result size of Desugar (after optimization)
  = {terms: 7, types: 5, coercions: 0}
*** Simplifier:
Result size of Simplifier = {terms: 7, types: 5, coercions: 0}
*** Tidy Core:
Result size of Tidy Core = {terms: 7, types: 5, coercions: 0}
*** CorePrep:
Result size of CorePrep = {terms: 9, types: 6, coercions: 0}
*** Stg2Stg:
*** CodeOutput:
*** New CodeGen:
*** CPSZ:
*** CPSZ:
```

Comment: facuq: can you submit your comment as an answer and accept it to remove this question from the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually a bug in GHC; it was confirmed on the GHC mailing list, and two people can reproduce it ([ghc's bug manager thread](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8870#ticket)).

Answer (score -1):

your ghc.exe path and cabal.exe path should be in your path variable

It has worked for me.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the error before? Just asking by interest.

Comment: If you have entered the link you would have seen that the bug was allready fixed, so of course It works for you. But I would bet You weren't able to reproduce it. So better don't post answers for stuff you can't even reproduce.

Comment: Yes,  this should be locked,  since the issue was fixed in a newer release,  but of course still affects 7.8rc2.